# Connecting to "drag and drop - add raster event" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, drag-and-drop

It is not clear to me how to connect to a [qgis.gui.QgisInterface](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgisInterface.html?highlight=addrasterlayer#qgis.gui.QgisInterface.registerCustomDropHandler) **drag and drop** event (signal) when adding a **new raster** to a project. I have tried to do this, but with no success:

```
def collapse_expanded_raster_layers():
    """Collapse all expanded raster layers"""
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    nodes = root.children()

    for node in nodes:
        layer = node.layer()
        if isinstance(layer, QgsRasterLayer):
            if node.isExpanded():
                node.setExpanded(False)


iface.actionAddRasterLayer().triggered.connect(collapse_expanded_raster_layers)
iface.actionAddOgrLayer().triggered.connect(collapse_expanded_raster_layers)
iface.actionAddPgLayer().triggered.connect(collapse_expanded_raster_layers)
iface.actionHideAllLayers().triggered.connect(collapse_expanded_raster_layers) # for testing only =)
```

I can connect to some events, but when I drag and drop a raster file into QGIS, nothing happens.

Comment: Look at `QgsProject` class signals : https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html?#qgis.core.QgsProject.layerWasAdded

Comment: @J.Monticolo Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits goes to [J.Monticolo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93097/j-monticolo):

```
def do_some_stuff(layers: list):
    for layer in layers:
        print(layer)

QgsProject.instance().layersAdded.connect(do_some_stuff)
```